# Runtime Error _bulk in inline (ie request)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning this great tool ElasticSearch.

Everything is in order:

1) executes the query:

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/website/blog/1?pretty'
```

I get:

```
{
"_index" : "website",
"_type" : "blog",
"_id" : "1",
"_version" : 15,
"found" : true,
"_source":{"title":"My first blog entry","text":"foo","tags":["testing 1"],"views":43}
}
```

2) perform _bulk:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary '
{"delete": { "_index": "website", "_type": "blog", "_id": "1" }}\n
{ "create": { "_index": "website", "_type": "blog", "_id": "1" }}\n
{ "title": "My first blog entry" }\n'
```

I get:

```
{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]",
 "status":400}
```

Why is that?

Thanks in advance).

Comment: I guess that you are not sending a new line character after each line including last one. If it's easier put the all the text in file and use ` --data-binary @/path/to/file.txt`

Comment: With the file, everything is clear. We are talking about inline query. I have a newline character is after each line, including the last one. Above is visible ).